# Foreign key annotation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a quite simple 3 table schema, but I couldn't find the solution for annotating the entity in Symfony2.

This are my tables:

```
user:
    id, name, joined

skill:
    id, name, created

user_skills: 
    user, skill
```

As you understand the last table can contain several rows for each customer and for each skill, but the there can not be duplicate rows with same `user` and `skill`.

How do I annotate the vars Entity of: `user_skills`

because it is not OneToMany, or ManyToMany, its a simple foreign key for other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my solution is right if you need all the users skills in Skill entity for later's DB queries. I guess this solution will be fine for you:

```
class UserSkills
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=\"your route"\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
     private $user;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=\"your route"\Entity\Skill")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="skill_id")
     */
     private $skill;
```